# Ambiguous call between Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.GetStringValue(System.Enum) and Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.GetStringValue(System.Enum)

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I have this problem with the code posted on this site https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs is the Google's developers site for Google Drive the quickstart. I ran it as it is on the site and it runs well. The problem comes when I try to use that code, or parts of it, in a desktop app that I am developing for academic purposes (please help), which needs to upload files to Google Drive. Obviously I can't have the prompt calls they use in the example (such as Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id); ). My question is how come it works fine on a basic promt app and when I try to reuse the code anywhere else is giving the error "ambiguous call between Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.GetStringValue(System.Enum) and Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.GetStringValue(System.Enum)"

Comment: Do you have two references to different versions of the same assembly, perhaps?

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot. I had the google.apis.silverlight reference... just deleted it and the red undrescoring went away. I know, rookie mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: well i tried to answer the question but because i am a newbie here i can´t. this is the text. The error was that, without thinking i added a lot of references to the project. within those was the google.api.silverlight reference. this was conflicting with another one, i still don't know which one but, for the sake of my deadline i will research the reasons later. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll write up an answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you get ambiguous calls to what appears to be the exact same method in the exact same fully-qualified type, that suggests that the same fully-qualified type name is exposed by two (or more!) assemblies that your project references.

In this case (as per the comments) you had references to both the Silverlight and "normal" desktop framework libraries.